# How to display heading and paragraph elements inline in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML code which contains one heading and 2 paragraph elements:

```
<div class="inter">

<h4>Note</h4>

<p>To add/remove a dependent or to modify your spouse's insurer information,  go to the My Life Events section and follow the instructions.</p>

<p>To modify your beneficiaries, please complete and sign the Beneficiary designation form and return it to your plan administrator.</p>

</div>
```

I want the above code to be displayed in the following way:[image]

I tried using `div.inter>p,h4 { display: inline;}` but by using this I am not able to create a line break between 2 paragraphs(as shown below).

> Note: To add/remove a dependent or to modify your spouse's insurer
>   information,  go to the My Life Events section and follow the
>   instructions.To modify your beneficiaries, please complete and sign
>   the Beneficiary designation form and return it to your plan
>   administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float the heading `<h4>`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.inter > h4 {
  float: left;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="inter">

  <h4>Note</h4>

  <p>To add/remove a dependent or to modify your spouse's insurer information, go to the My Life Events section and follow the instructions.</p>

  <p>To modify your beneficiaries, please complete and sign the Beneficiary designation form and return it to your plan administrator.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following css and your good to go.

```
.inter h4, p:nth-of-type(1) { display: inline !important;}
```

Sample: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/edwqZz

Answer (score -1):

H2.... are block level element.

Better use H4 instead of span tag . Because if use span tag means no need to write code for same line

*"span tag is default inline element only"*

then what ever style write in span. Try to make code for easily.